# What is the relationship between the node_modules directory and package.json?

Tags: npm

Is the structure of dependencies in `node_modules` simply a mirror of the dependency tree structure found in `package.json`? Or does performing `npm install` download what is in `package.json` and organize `node_modules` in some special way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally `package.json` will correspond to `node_modules`. Running `npm install` (with no arguments) will install all the packages described in `package.json` into `node_modules`, but running `npm install somepackage` won't modify `package.json` unless you use the `--save` option.

You can also use `npm list` to check if your `node_modules` and `package.json` are in sync. Packages in `package.json` that aren't in `node_modules` are tagged `UNMET DEPENDENCY`, whereas packages in `node_modules` but not in `package.json` are tagged `extraneous`.

Also note that the root `package.json` doesn't contain the full dependency tree; it only contains the list of direct dependencies. Dependencies of dependencies are listed in the `package.json` files of the dependencies themselves, recursively.

Comment: I was under the impression that running "npm install <some package> --save" would add that dependency to package.json then download it to node_modules. Is that correct?